# Protecting dlls in setup and deployment (visual studio 2008)

Tags: c#, class, dll, shared-libraries

This may be a very basic question, but I was unable to find any answers on the subject. I have a project that references several class library dlls that were also written in Visual Studio 2008. The setup file installs perfectly fine and puts the dlls in the appropriate locations. It seems, however, that any one of the dlls can be used by anyone that has installed the setup project. For instance, if I have a dll that performs numerous proprietary functions, how do I keep someone from simply taking the installed dll, referencing it in their own project, and using the available functions?

I assume this is an easy fix, but I am a beginner in the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the only way to do this would be to just include all the functions which are currently in the DLLs in your executable, and set modifiers to private.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to prevent that (apart from obscurity - no-one knows how the API to your DLLs is meant to be used).  All you can do is give obscure names to your API functions.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by placing some static token in your dll, which acts as a private key between your project, and if this key isn't set then no methods execute. This private token would be added by your entry point. Unfortunately this means you have to check the token on every public method call.